# Sinónimo para la etiqueta [makefile]

Tags: discusión, desambiguación-etiquetas

Propongo crear un sinónimo para la etiqueta `make` y unificarla con la etiqueta `makefile`.

### Argumentos

1. no se puede usar un makefile sin make
2. si bien hay diferentes implementaciones como cmake y gnu-make es común que se les referencie simplemente como make y que usen un makefile

Comment: Yo no diría que son diferentes versiones. Simplemente son diferentes productos con un mismo propósito (o similar) y lo resuelven a su manera. Nadie dice que todos los autos son diferentes versiones de uno en particular.

Comment: corregido, alguna otra cosa?

Comment: Solamente eso.​